# Is it possible to image upload on a particular size using a control panel?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce

I am using the commerce plugin. I want to display an image of the specific size without CSS is there any specific way in the commerce plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use image transform option for that.

You should go to control panel and go to below path
Settings > Assets > Image Transforms

Then create new image transform.
Using it, you can control height, width, image quality, image format and other things as well.